# what should I do when format tsconfig.json without change spaces and commas?

Tags: json, prettier-vscode

I want to format tsconfig.json without change spaces and commas.
this tsc --init config
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6EeJ.png)

after format,spaces and commas change.
what should I do?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZoUR.png)

Answer (score 0):

The commas are going to be placed at the end of those multi-line comments (**/* ... */**). So you would have to remove them or put them on independent lines.

**Quickly get rid of multi-line comments in Visual Studio Code**

1. CTRL + H
2. Tick `Use Regular Expression`
3. Paste `\s* \/\* .* \*\/`
4. Click `Replace all`